# Error starting expo app from GitHub repository

Tags: react-native, mobile, expo

I downloaded this expo app from gitHub, but when i start it it asks for a username and account, i put mine and gives an error:

```
  Log in to EAS
        ✔ Email or username … josiaslopo
        ✔ Email or username … josiaslopo
        ✔ Password … ****************
        ✔ Password … ****************
    
    ApiV2Error: Entity Not Authorized.
```

Can't really find an answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.